# Basic variable passing confusion

Tags: java

I found a tutorial online, but I don't really get how could result be this:

```
Passed Name is :tommy
```

Here's the code:

```
public class Puppy {

    public Puppy(String name) {
        // This constructor has one parameter, name.
        System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Following statement would create an object myPuppy
        Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy("tommy");
    }
}
```

Where exactly does it say `name = tommy`? I thought it could at least use something like  `("passed Name is :" + myPuppy)`.

Could anyone help me understand this?

Comment: myPuppy is a Puppy object that has been passed the name "tommy" to its constructor, the println prints whatever name is passed to the constructor.

Comment: Grab a book and learn some fundamentals first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you pass as a constructor argument

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "tommy" ); // the String reference to "tommy"
```

is bound to the constructor parameter `name`

```
public Puppy(String name){
```

Answer (score 1):

It never says `name = tommy`, you're right about that. The constructor function is only printing the `String name` parameter that is passed to it (not actually setting a member name variable for a class instance of `Puppy').

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program, your main method is executed.

So you execute this line

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "tommy" );
```

It means "Create varriable myPuppy which type is Puppy.
And then create new object with constructor which takes exactly one String as a variable and this string has value "tommy".

This is a constructor, it has the same name as class and no void/return parameter

```
public Puppy(String name)
```

So it is run and there you execute this line

```
System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name );
```

In variable name is "tommy".

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "tommy" ); // the String reference to "tommy"
```

Note that "myPuppy" is a variable name in your java program, but "tommy" is the String value that you are passing to the Puppy class constructor.

therefor, in the line:

```
System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name );
```

the java variable "name" has the value "tommy", so that´s why the final result is the expected:

"Passed Name is :tommy"

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad example of passing variables. Its one class with main and a constructor. What is a constructor is the right question. In java you can have classes, if a method in that class is named same as the class then that is a constructor. a constructor creates an object a lot like the primitive objects you are familiar with like int, boolean, float etc... The big difference being that this object has methods attached to it, other primitives, pointers, other objects. To pass variables from one method to the other there is two ways. One you pass a pointer, two you pass a value.

In this example you are not passing a variable you are creating an object with value "tommy" the constructor of this object expects a string to be inserted. and then the object is printing to the screen the statement as part of its construction.

Comment: _To pass variables from one method to the other there is two ways. One you pass a pointer, two you pass a value._ Java is pass by value, always. Careful how you phrase it.

Comment: Again, it is the wording you should be careful about. There are no pointers in Java, only references and primitives and both are passed by value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and Ervin: I don't believe that this is the right time for the OP to learn the intricacies of passing parameters as values vs values of references vs directly by reference.

Comment: @hexafraction But I like having this argument.

Comment: What happens when we pass an object? is that not a pointer? true its the value of that pointer but still is passing a reference and you can edit the items of that object using that reference?

Comment: @ErvinSe Here's the thing. We pass a *value* of a *reference* to an object.

Comment: If I were to reassign the string in the method then the original reference is untouched.